# How to select data from a char array in C?

Tags: c, string, char

I have this char array:

```
char rcv_str = 1001ff;
```

But I want to do something like this:

```
id = 10;
sts = 01;
```

Until then I couldn't make this separation. Any suggestions?

Comment: neither `char rcv_str` is an array (it's a single character) nor is `1001ff` (that's an interger constant with an invalid suffix ff, it shouldn't even compile)

Comment: If you want to work on char arrays, please do it. Do you want to extract substrings from a bigger array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your rcv_str is always the same size you could do some thing like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char rcv_str[] = "1001ff";
    char id[3];
    char sts[3];
    strncpy ( id, rcv_str, 2 );
    strncpy ( sts, &rcv_str[2], 2 );
    
    // Null terminate strings
    id[2] = 0;  
    sts[2] = 0;
    
    printf("id: %s sts: %s\n", id, sts);
    
    return 0;
}
```